# Codeforces Problem 110A - Trouble with a certain input

Tags: c++, algorithm

Problem:

> Petya loves lucky numbers. We all know that lucky numbers are the positive integers whose decimal representations contain only the lucky digits 4 and 7. For example, numbers 47, 744, 4 are lucky and 5, 17, 467 are not.
>
> Unfortunately, not all numbers are lucky. Petya calls a number nearly lucky if the number of lucky digits in it is a lucky number. He wonders whether number n is a nearly lucky number.
>
> Input
> The only line contains an integer n (1 ≤ n ≤ 10<sup>18</sup>).
>
> Output
> Print on the single line "YES" if n is a nearly lucky number. Otherwise, print "NO" (without the quotes).

I submitted a solution on this problem and fail at the input of `4744000695826`. This should give an output of `YES`, since it has 4 lucky numbers, and 4 is a lucky number itself. However I get an output of `NO`. This was the first input test which contained 4s and 7s and was bigger than 32 bit int limit 2<sup>32</sup>-1, so I guess that has something to do with it, but I honestly don't know.

Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
 
// counting digits in an int
int count_digit(int number) {
    return int(log10(number) + 1);
}
 
// counting certain digits in an int
int counter(int b, int n) {
    int count = 0;
    while(b > 0) {
        if(b % 10 == n) {
            count++;
        }
        b /= 10;
    }
    return count;
}
 
int main()
{
    int k;
    cin >> k;
    int r = counter(k,4) + counter(k,7);
    if (count_digit(r) - (counter(r,4) + counter(r,7)) == 0) {
        cout << "YES";
    }
    else {
        cout << "NO";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please include all necessary information in the quesiton. What is a lucky number?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number check the link at the top of the entry

Comment: The value `4744000695826` is most likely too big for your `int` type. Use `int64_t` (or `long long int`) instead. (I tried your code changing all the `int` to `int64_t` and I got "YES" for that number.)

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: @InsertaRandomNameNow please include all necessary information in the question _itself_.  Visiting other websites should not be a requirement to read your question.

Comment: Why are you using an int to try and hold a number you know can be larger than an int?

Comment: there are two very useful skills you can learn here. Using a debugger and writing tests. This is my test of your `count_digit`: https://godbolt.org/z/18W3M4acn.

Comment: The website you link even *tells* you that you need 64-bit integers.

Comment: btw you do not need to count the digits seperately, thats rather inefficient. You need only a single pass through the digits. Unfortunately thats something such online coding challenges won't teach you because it does not impact complexity :/

Comment: @AdrianMole thanks, that worked, but in this case, is it necessary to change all ints to long long?

Comment: Well, I guess your `counter` and `count` don't need to be that big. Most others do, that I can see on a quick inspection.

Comment: @NathanOliver I tried using a debugger, but whenever I get to any line of code containing cin, the debugger just stops letting me step over, even though I type in the inputs.

Comment: Did you type in the input and press enter?

Comment: @NathanOliver yep

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number thanks I'll look through it

Comment: @InsertaRandomNameNow You could take a look at the answer you've gotten.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to process numbers greater than your ints, you need to use something else.

For example, you could:

```
std::string number;
std::cin >> number;
```

Then you can check the number with

```
char value = '5'; 
for(const char& c: number)
{
    if (c == value);
}
```

That way you're not even limited to 64 bits.

Even more modern/idiomatic would be to use std::count:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count

Comment: In this situation, `std::count/_if()` would make more sense than a manual `for` loop.

Comment: Agreed, but I didn't even want to read the codeforce statement :-). I just read enough to see "Oh they want to test individual chars"

Comment: I would actually consider to use `std::accumulate` to count `7`s and `4`s in one pass

Comment: `std::count_if` _reads_ a bit better (in my book). - I've reached my voting limit ... can't vote for comments :-)